# TypeScript Errors - Duplicate Function Declaration / Cannot redeclare Block-Scoped Variable

Tags: typescript

So I'm working through the 'TypeScript in 5 Minutes':

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html

But I keep getting error after error (not great when trying to show a colleague TS).

For example, using this example (the very first one):

```
function greeter(name) {
  return 'Hello ' + name;
}

let user = 'Test';

console.log(greeter(user));
```

Even the above, extremely simple TS example gives me 2 errors.

**First Error** - Highlights the 'greeter' in the function declaration and says: 'Duplicate Function Declaration'

**Second Error** - Highlights the 'user' declaration and says: 'Cannot redeclare block scoped variable user'

[image: TS Error]

I have followed these guides a few times now and never experienced this.

I have attempted disabling any Plugins I think may be conflicting with it (Prettier / ESLint) but I'm still receiving the same error.

I was originally having problems, but I identified an erronous PATH variable that was forcing TS to v 1.0.0.3 however, I have now resolved this and the correct TSC version is found.

I can't figure out why I'm receiving errors even on the very first example?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Almost don't want to post this, but the issue was that as I had the .js file and the .ts file open side-by-side, they were conflicting with each other.

Having just one of the files open at once removes all the errors.

Aaaaah!